# HttpFile::SendRequest and character encoding

Tags: c++, mysql, character-encoding, mfc, http-post

I want to submit a form using the CHttpFile::SendRequest and save those data to a mysql database.  The field inside the DB table collation is also set to utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

It works fine except the character encoding for the non-english chars. My app is under MFC and "character set" is no set which means ASCII. I tried to convert the chars to unicode without success.

```
CString     strFormData;
strFormData = _T(SUBMIT_FORM) + _T(strSubmitValue) +  _T(USERNAME_FIELD) + _T(m_strUsername) + _T(RESTORE_EMAIL_FIELD) + _T(m_strRestoreEmail) + _T(CAPTCHA_FIELD);

LPWSTR lpUnicodeFormData = A2W( strFormData );    
strHeaders = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n");        
result = pFile->SendRequest(strHeaders, (LPVOID) (LPCTSTR) lpUnicodeFormData, wcslen(lpUnicodeFormData));
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Difficult so say what's going wrong here with only three lines of code.

Comment: If *Character Set* is *Not set*, the encoding defaults to ANSI, not ASCII. The `A2W` macro properly converts an ANSI string to a UTF-16 Unicode string. Apparently you need (and promised to have) UTF-8, though. You need [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) to convert from ANSI to UTF-16 followed by [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8. You cannot convert from ANSI to UTF-8 directly.

Comment: Yes ANSI is the correct sorry for my mistake. Anyway you say that  I have one more step to complete the job. To convert wide char to multi byte. Right ? Question utf-16 = wide char while utf-8 = multibyte? I am little confused here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the rest of the code is useless for the question. What do you need more ?

Comment: What is your data? If your project is ANSI and `strFormData` is ANSI then don't do any conversion.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani yes it's all ANSI, data and my project, but I have problem as I described for non English chars.

Comment: Show how you declare `strFormData` and how you assign it. If your ANSI program is taking user input as ANSI then `strFormData` is wrong for non-Latin languages, it has lost information and can't be fixed. If `strFormData` is from a UTF8 file then use it directly as binary data without any conversion.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I added in my original post the extra code you need (the declaration of the strFormData as well as the way I assign its value).

Debugging the code the strFormData is keeping the non-latin chars until the time SendRequest is called. I will try right now to view the post values from the server's side but before save them in the DB. I will let you know.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I just tried the get back to my mfc app, the sql query returned from the web server and just before it executes it. It seems just fine. The non latin chars was just fine under a CString variable. Then, I copied this string value from the Visual Studio and pasted/run the sql query, directly under phpmyadmin. It worked like a charm.

Comment: [Last update] Before I finish the previous answer, I run again the html form directly from the web server online just to be sure that it works as it supposed to work. I  surprised to find out that I had problem with non latin chars in this case. So MFC/C++ seems that is not responsible for that error. I will focus to the php code instead. Thanks !!

Comment: UTF-16 and UTF-8 are both multibyte character encodings, where *code units* consist of 16-bit and 8-bit numbers, respectively. One or more code unit form a single *code point*. Code points uniquely map to characters/glyphs, whereas code units must be interpreted differently for different encodings. If this is still confusing, have a look at [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). This a very compact and easy to digest introduction.

Comment: In addition to reading @IInspectable 's link I would recommend you write a small c++ program and test conversion between UTF8 and UTF16. This will save time in future. You are using ANSI MFC + WinInet + PHP, + `T` macro plus other stuff which hides ANSI/Unicode definitions ... If your code works it's only a happy coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Inside PHP file where the html form exists, I added the code

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

This solved the problem.

thank you to all.